# Commercial-compatible licensed SNMP Agent for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, snmp

I know there are other questions that pertain to writing an SNMP Agent for .NET. They generally point to 2 open source projects that are LGPL. I'm looking for an example with a more permissive license such as MIT or MSPL.

Are there examples of an SNMP Agent exist in one of those licenses?

**Edit** I'm only concerned about Windows. No need for Mono support.

Answer (score 0):

Recent changes in #SNMP licensing model makes it suitable for your requirements,

http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=600012&version=3

Starting from its 8.0 release (currently in master branch, https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib), all agent classes (under Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Pipeline and Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Objects) are moved to SharpSnmpLib.Engine.dll assembly, and re-licensed under MIT/X11. In this way, you can modify or replace any of them freely without being Lesser GPLed.

The core assembly SharpSnmpLib.dll is still licensed under Lesser GPL, as it is for SNMP communication only, and you don't need to modify it for agent development in almost all cases. It cannot be re-licensed, as it does depends on Lesser GPL code.